# Can a user hack a server running apache from a website

Tags: linux, webserver, apache

Is it possible that a user can hack a server running Apache `httpd` from the website it hosts? Let's say I have a PHP web application running under Apache with explicit user `www-data` in the virtual host configuration. If the user hacks the website, he would only have access to modify the PHP code, since he only has the privileges of the `www-data` user.

Could the attacker leverage this limited access to reach user or system files, effectively taking control of the operating system?

Comment: What you describe happens often. It is possible to use weaknesses in the PHP code to gain access to the OS. Not how you describe it, though.

Comment: @VipulNair Can you be more specific?

Comment: @schroeder As the php code is executed by Apache so, the user `www-data` does not restrict file access? Because if I don't `chown www-data folder`, PHP returns an `access denied error`.

Comment: Think of it in stages. If you have the appropriate levels of controls, the attacker needs to find a different way through each layer. Each layer might require very different ways through. If the site, and the server, is poorly written enough to not have any layers, it is possible to simply hack the site and gain root access. For instance, if the site was running as root.

Comment: If your question is *really* about whether an attacker could attack *your* site with all your controls and protections in place, we can't answer that. We can give general answers, though.

Comment: Did you mean `chown` or `chroot`? It's no surprise that PHP would need to own the files it needs ...

Comment: @schroeder It's `chown`. If a file has `www-data` `rw` permissions, PHP can interact with that file because Apache runs the Php script as `www-data` user if I'm not wrong about the use of the apache user in the configuration file.

Comment: I think that you need to understand what these commands do and how the user security works in Linux. You are asking some very, very basic questions. `chown` does not restrict the user to only having access to those files.

Comment: @schroeder From my understanding, `chown user folder` says that `folder` is owned by that `user`. So the `user` and `root` only can access `folder`. No other user can access `folder` if the permission `other` does not set to `r` or `w` or `rw`.

Comment: @schroeder I understand your point. My question is about can a script running by apache under user `www-data` or `any other user` have read or write access to files that does not grant access to `www-data` or `any other user`.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that www-data cannot also access other files. That's the danger and the thing you need to restrict.

Comment: My answer below tells you the other side of the coin. Just because you restrict www-data to just the PHP project does not ***also mean*** that the data it can access won't be able to permit it to elevate.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Last question. What do you mean by layer in `If you have the appropriate levels of controls, the attacker needs to find a different way through each layer.`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose that the site allows uploads without protection and I am able to upload a [PHP shell](https://n0where.net/php-webshells). I access the shell, which gives me terminal access. At this point, I am running commands on the operating system as `www-data` or whatever user the site is configured to run as.

Now I can hunt around for configuration files that might have root passwords in it or vulnerabilities in the OS that would let me gain root access. Now I'm using the PHP, served by Apache, to run commands as root.

Once I get root, I can obviously also gain access to any user's files on the system. The system is mine (and anyone else who accesses the shell).

This is just one of many possibilities.

Comment: That's a good warning. You said: _Now I can hunt around for configuration files that might have root passwords in it_. Those `configuration files` are just `configuration files` in the PHP project? Because if a file does not have `www-data` read permission and does not give access to `other` the PHP script won't be able to open the configuration files. Or can it?

Comment: Whatever the user has access to. You are asking very specific questions about how you might have configured your system, and I won't comment on that without being able to see your full configuration (and doing that it off-topic here). The prinicples are established, though.